# How do I set up class in PageObject?

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm new in Selenium, I use IntelliJ, Selenium WebDriver, Junit. My problem is set up TestBase class in PageObject. This is my TestBase class:
package TestBaseSetup;

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class TestBase  {

    WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @Before
    public void testSetUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Dragana\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe ");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized", "--disable-cache");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.navigate().to("http://store.demoqa.com/");
    }
    @After
    public void testTearDown(){
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

This is my test class:

```
package test;

import PageObjectPage.HomePage;
import PageObjectPage.LogInResultPage;
import PageObjectPage.MyAccount;
import TestBaseSetup.TestBase;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class AccountTest extends TestBase {


    protected WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldLogIn() {

        HomePage onHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
        System.out.println("Step 1 ");
        MyAccount onMyAccount = onHomePage.clickOnMyAccount();
        System.out.println("Step 2");
        LogInResultPage onResultPage = onMyAccount.LogIn().submitForm();
        System.out.println("Step 3");
        wait(2000);
        Assert.assertTrue(onResultPage.getMessage().contains("ERROR"));
    }

    public void wait(int seconds){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

These are page in PageObject: 
HomePage page:

```
package PageObjectPage;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class HomePage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){

        this.driver=driver;
    }

   public MyAccount clickOnMyAccount(){
        //Click on My Account
        driver.findElement(By.className("account_icon")).click();

        return new MyAccount(driver);
    }

    //public HomePage navigateToWebApp(){

       // return new HomePage();
    //}
    public void wait(int seconds){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

MyAccount page:

```
package PageObjectPage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class MyAccount {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public MyAccount(WebDriver driver){

        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public MyAccount LogIn(){
        //Fill in the text box username
        driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("Dragana");
        //Fill in the text box password
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("123456");

        return new MyAccount(driver);
    }
    public LogInResultPage submitForm() {
        //Click on button Log in
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        return new LogInResultPage();
    }
}
```

LogInResultPage page:

```
package PageObjectPage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


public class LogInResultPage {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public LogInResultPage(){
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        //Printing message
        return driver.findElement(By.tagName("p")).getText();

    }

}
```

My problem is when I run test outputs this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -ea -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.1\bin" -Didea.junit.sm_runner -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\workspace\proba\target\test-classes;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-java-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-chrome-driver-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-remote-driver-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-api-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\3.2.4\cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.3.1\gson-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\19.0\guava-19.0.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.2\httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.4\httpcore-4.4.4.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.2\httpmime-4.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.1.0\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\4.1.0\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-edge-driver-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-firefox-driver-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-ie-driver-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-opera-driver-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-safari-driver-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.5.7.Final\netty-3.5.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.0.0-beta3\selenium-support-3.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\Dragana\.m2\repository\com\codeborne\phantomjsdriver\1.3.0\phantomjsdriver-1.3.0.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 test.AccountTest,shouldLogIn
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 9660
Only local connections are allowed.
Dec 05, 2016 3:41:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Dec 05, 2016 3:41:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Step 1 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PageObjectPage.HomePage.clickOnMyAccount(HomePage.java:18)
    at test.AccountTest.shouldLogIn(AccountTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

I don't know where is problem when I run this project. Thanks.

Comment: public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    } Initialize your WebDriver object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PageFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) in order to use PageObjects, for example in PageObjectPage.HomePage.clickOnMyAccount(MyAccount.java:18)
you should return something like this:

```
return PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), SettingsPage.class);
```

and when you start your test, the first page should be initialize like this:

```
HomePage onHomePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage .class);
```

and create a PageBase class(all pages (Home, Account need to extend this), with something like this:

```
protected WebDriver driver;
public PageBase(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}
public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return this.driver;
}
```

with this you can remove all the:

```
    private WebDriver driver;
```

in the pages.
Also the Pages that extends PageObjects should be initialize like this:

```
public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
}
```

Comment: When I wrote the code that you gave me to test displays the same error. Do I need to add something in the code or do you have another solution?

Comment: its possible that something is missing, paste the actual code and the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This is my TestBase set up class:

```
package TestBaseSetup;

import PageObjectPage.BasePage;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;


public class TestBase {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void testSetUp(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Dragana\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe ");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized", "--disable-cache");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.navigate().to("http://store.demoqa.com/");
    }

    @After
    public void testTearDown(){

        driver.close();
    }

}
```

This is BasePage class:

```
package PageObjectPage;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class BasePage {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    public BasePage (WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }

    }
```

These are pages in PageObject:
HomePage:

```
package PageObjectPage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using = "account_icon")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement button_my_accout;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){

        super(driver);
    }

   public MyAccount clickOnMyAccount(){
        //Click on My Account
       button_my_accout.click();

       return PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), MyAccount.class);

    }

}
```

MyAccount page:

```
package PageObjectPage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;


public class MyAccount extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(id = "log")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement username;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "pwd")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement password;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "login")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement login_button;


    public MyAccount(WebDriver driver){

        super(driver);
    }

    public MyAccount LogIn(){
        //Fill in the text box username
        username.sendKeys("Dragana");
        //Fill in the text box password
        password.sendKeys("123456");

        return new MyAccount(driver);
    }
    public LogInResultPage submitForm() {
        //Click on button Log in
        login_button.click();

        return new LogInResultPage(driver);
    }
}
```

LogInResultPage:

```
package PageObjectPage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LogInResultPage extends BasePage{

    public LogInResultPage(WebDriver driver){

        super(driver);
    }
    public String getMessage(){
        //Printing message
        return driver.findElement(By.tagName("p")).getText();

    }

}
```

This is test page:

```
package test;

import PageObjectPage.HomePage;
import PageObjectPage.LogInResultPage;
import PageObjectPage.MyAccount;
import TestBaseSetup.TestBase;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;


public class AccountTest extends TestBase {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void shouldLogIn() {


        HomePage onHomePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
        System.out.println("Step 1 ");
        MyAccount onMyAccount = onHomePage.clickOnMyAccount();
        System.out.println("Step 2");
        LogInResultPage onResultPage = onMyAccount.LogIn().submitForm();
        System.out.println("Step 3");
        wait(2000);
        Assert.assertTrue(onResultPage.getMessage().contains("ERROR"));
    }

    public void wait(int seconds){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a problem:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.click(Unknown Source)
    at PageObjectPage.HomePage.clickOnMyAccount(HomePage.java:25)
    at test.AccountTest.shouldLogIn(AccountTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test script you have not initialised `WebDriver` hence there is issue. For e.g. in `AccountTest` , driver which is being used is not initialised. You can put a debug point and check its value. Or else in `constructor` of your `TestBase` , you can initialise it and then try to execute. It should work then. 
Like below:

```
public TestBase(){
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("--start-maximized", "--disable-cache");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

Let me know if that approach helps or need any help

Comment: I am copied code that you write to me, and then came out second error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
at TestBaseSetup.TestBase.<init>(TestBase.java:18)
 at test.AccountTest.<init>(AccountTest.java:13)

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path_to_chromedriver"); Use this to set property for chromedriver

Comment: This is set in TestBase class:
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Dragana\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe ");

Comment: Set it inside constructor of TestBase and see of that helps

Comment: Please check the path to chromedriver of try setting it in in test class if that does not help please edit post eith your latest code

Comment: Set following in constructor of TestBase class: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Dragana\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe "); and try to debug

Comment: When I set construcor in class TestBase browser opens repeatedly and error is the same.